# CMakeList find_package OpenCV SVN

Tags: ros, opencv, manifest.xml, find-package, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have the following problem, which drives me crazy.
I installed ROS fuerte with ros-fuerte-opencv2.
I also compiled OpenCV from the svn repositories because
I need CUDA and OpenGL support which is not included by ros opencv.

However, my rosnode always gets linked against the ROS opencv libraries.
e.g.: libopencv_highgui.so.2.3 => /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3

my manifest.xml

```
    <package>
  <description brief="test">

     test

  </description>
  <author>andreas</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/test</url>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="cv_bridge"/>
  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depend package="image_transport"/>
  <rosdep name="opencv2.3.3"/>

</package>
```

before ros opencv got updated to versionn 2.3.3 it worked fine by the way.
Now there's apparently no distinction between the version numbers any more.

My CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

find_package(OpenCV 2.3.3 REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT)
find_package(OpenGL)

rosbuild_init()

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_add_library(CGaborKernel src/helper/CGaborKernel.cpp)
rosbuild_add_library(memory_stat src/helper/memory_stat.cpp)

find_package(CUDA)
if(CUDA_FOUND)
    rosbuild_add_executable(img_node_cuda src/img_node_cuda.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(img_node_cuda CGaborKernel memory_stat ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif()
```

I made it work for the moment by copying the svn libraries over the ros opencv libraries, but that's obiously the worst solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32284/cmakelist-find_package-opencv-svn/) by [andreas__](https://answers.ros.org/users/1875/andreas__/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you're using the regular [CMake find_package](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) mechanism, it picks up the system-installed OpenCV first. The ROS fuerte setup sets your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable. You can try to override it by putting your local CMake installation path in front of the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, or exporting the variable OpenCV_DIR to point to your local installation containing OpenCVConfig.cmake.

And yes, I agree that copying stuff over your system-installed OpenCV is a bad idea. It will break most ROS libs depending on it if it's not binary-compatible.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3